# ES6 group array objects by field type

Tags: javascript, collections, ecmascript-6

Is there a terse es6 functional way to group items by type in that it's immutable?

**accounts.json**

```
   [
         {"account": {"name": "Bob's credit", "type": "credit", "id": "1"}},
         {"account": {"name": "savings", "type": "savings", "id": "2"}},
         {"account": {"name": "vacation savings", "type": "savings", "id": "3"}},
         {"account": {"name": "son's savings", "type": "savings", "id": "4"},
         {"account": {"name": "wife's credit card", "type": "savings", "id": "5"}
   ]
```

**Expected**

```
[
{"savings": [
    {"account": {"name": "savings", "type": "savings", "id": "2"}},
    {"account": {"name": "vacation savings", "type": "savings", "id": "3"}},
    {"account": {"name": "son's savings", "type": "savings", "id": "4"}
]},

{"checking": [
   {"account": {"name": "wife's credit card", "type": "savings", "id": "5"}
]
```

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: there is no built-in function in es6 to achieve that, you need to filter the array by yourself or using third-party library like lodash.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group your list by its elements inner `type` property :

```js
const data = [
     {"account": {"name": "Bob's credit", "type": "credit", "id": "1"}},
     {"account": {"name": "savings", "type": "savings", "id": "2"}},
     {"account": {"name": "vacation savings", "type": "savings", "id": "3"}},
     {"account": {"name": "son's savings", "type": "savings", "id": "4"}},
     {"account": {"name": "wife's credit card", "type": "savings", "id": "5"}}
];

const res = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(!acc[curr.account.type]) acc[curr.account.type] = []; //If this type wasn't previously stored
  acc[curr.account.type].push(curr);
  return acc;
},{});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the latest release function Object.groupBy(array, callbackFun):

```
const result = Object.groupBy(data, ({type}) => type);
```

the code is more conscise and readeable.

Comment: `o => o.type` is even more concise :-)